# Can you add httpclients to services without having to specify each one

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 6 app that uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`.  A typical service is defined by an interface and the implementation as follows:

```
public interface IAddressService
{
    Task<List<Address>?> List();
    Task<List<Address>?> List(int appid);
    Task<Address?> Get(int id);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage?> Update(Address Address);
    Task<Address?> Add(Address Address);
}

public class AddressService : IAddressService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public AddressService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    async Task<List<Address>?> IAddressService.List()
    {
        List<Address>? ret;

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/Addresses");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ret = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Address>>
                          (await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
        }
        else
        {
            ret = new List<Address>();
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

and so forth.  I have one for each table of the database.  In the `ConfigureServices`, I wire them up like this:

```
services.AddTransient<MPSHttpHandler>();

services.AddHttpClient<IAddressService, AddressService>(client =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"] ?? "");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpHandler>();
```

I have to specify every service(client).  I was wondering if there were a way to do something like:

```
var clients = typeof(Program).Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .ToList();

clients.ForEach(client =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient<client.Interface, client.Implementation>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"] ?? "");
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpHandler>();
});
```

I don't know how to get the client type to a form where I can use them in the call to `AddHttpClient`.  Is there a way to do this?

---

**Update #1**

I implemented the method per the example by @Guru Stron.  I changed the types to match the signature of `AddHttpClient`.  I created the `static` class as follows:

```
public static class MyHttpClientRegExts
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Settings:ApiAddress"] ?? "");
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpHandler>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the lambda action for client =>

> CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in method of type 'func<HttpClient, TImplementaion>'

This tells me that it is using the overload

```
AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>(IServiceCollection, Func<HttpClient,TImplementation>)
```

rather than the overload:

```
AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>(IServiceCollection, Action<HttpClient>)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have tagged your question with .NET 6 and 7. Which one are we talking about?

Comment: This applies to both really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit more reflection by constructing and invoking generic method (the `AddHttpClient` implementation does some internal stuff so it would be better to reuse then trying to repeat). The easiest way would be to move the setup into separate static class:

```cs
public static class MyHttpClientRegExts
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration Configuration) where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(...);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MPSHttpHandler>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And then use it to setup every service. Something to get you started:

```cs
var types = typeof(Program).Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t is { IsAbstract: false, IsClass: true } && t.Name.EndsWith("Service")) // find implementation types
    .ToList();

// find the setup method
var method = typeof(MyHttpClientRegExts).GetMethod(nameof(MyHttpClientRegExts.AddCustomHttpClient));
foreach (var implType in types)
{
    // find interface type to register, maybe will need some refinement 
    var interfaceType = implType.GetInterfaces().Single(i => i.Name.EndsWith("Service"));
    // create closed generic method and invoke to register the type pair
    method.MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType, implType)
        .Invoke(null, new object?[] { services, Configuration });
}
```

Comment: I did an update on my Original Post.  Please take a look.  I am one error away from it working.  Thanks, Jim.

Comment: @JimWilcox the code I've posted worked for me (though I've used .NET 7). Not sure what is wrong with yours, maybe some `using`s are missing. Can you post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: The problem is yours adds an httphandler of type IAddressService each time rather than the type you are passing to the function.  If you can't pass the parameter type, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @JimWilcox updated it to work with generic types. But still - works for me)

Comment: @JimWilcox note that correct `AddHttpClient` method comes from `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package and is in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace (`HttpClientFactoryServiceCollection` class)

Comment: You modified the method signature as well.  I didn't notice this.  Once I fixed that so that it knows the types coming in, it started working.  Thanks so much for your help!